# How to properly setup cron job on Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I recently setup a cron job on my EC2 instance. I have my file "test.py" uploaded to this instance and would like it to run at a set time every week.

The type of instance I am using is Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03.0 (HVM)

From within my EC2 instance using PuTTy I used `crontab -e` to edit the crontab file. I entered:

```
30 12 * * 2 python /home/ec2-user/test.py
```

to have it run every Tuesday at 12:30.

Now, whenever I do `crontab -l` the newly created cron is shown but it has not been running for whatever reason.

Did I use the wrong file path for my test.py file that's on the EC2 instance?

I am unsure as to how to progress.

Answer (score 1):

first check, whether this line ("python /home/ec2-user/test.py") is running properly or not on your console. If yes, then you have to add path in your crontab. you can copy all the paths from path variable using "echo $PATH" and along with add the path of the folder where your test.py is present. and paste it at the top of your crontab.
eg - 
PATH = /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin: ... :/home/ec2-user
30 12 * * 2 python /home/ec2-user/test.py

Comment: Where do i go within console to test whether "python /home/ec2-user/test.py" is working properly? im new to using Amazon Web Services @Shivam

Comment: try running on the terminal.

Comment: ah yes right before you messaged back i knew tried it. i thought you meant AWS console lol, but yes it did start running when i tried your suggestion. So the file path is correct, thank you for narrowing that down @Shivam

Comment: however the cronjob still wont work...hmmmm @Shivam

Comment: Lol. by mistakenly i typed console. sorry for confusing you.

Comment: have you added "PATH=/..." at the top of crontab? this worked for me.

Comment: could you elaborate more on what you mean by the top of crontab? @Shivam

Comment: when you type "echo $PATH" on your terminal,you will get all the paths separated by " : " . copy all, paste in notepad and also add your folder path where test.py file present.  now open crontab -e, paste - "PATH= your new string which you have pasted in notepad"   at the beginning of your crontab

Comment: ahh okay so will i have to make a new notepad file and then download it into my ec2 with cmd on my computer? or is there a way to do this all on the instance itself? @Shivam

Comment: just figured out what you said to try and am now implementing a test :) hopefully it will work! will let you know positive progress as it occurs @Shivam

Comment: havent been able to get it working :( thanks for asking <3 @Shivam

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Linux doesnt like crontab -e. instead take the same config and place it in /etc/cron.d/ with any name you want without any extension and be done with it. Make sure you change the permissions to 0644 on the file you save. It will execute based on the time schedule you set.

Comment: when you say same config do you mean the cron job? and also how does one place the config into "/etc/cron.d/"? i just typed that in on terminal and it said "Is a directory"...i feel like you put me on the right track @Michael Quale

Comment: Just cd in that folder, create a file use the same cron format you are trying to save in crontab and save it in that location instead. Name it whatever you want that is easy to recognize. Make sure the file permissions are 0644. ie chmod filename 0644.

Comment: @Zzz1324 Did this solve your issue? If so, please accept answer :)

Comment: Working on configuring it today! :) will keep you posted and if it works will accept answer :D @Michael Quale